# Получить значения всех классов атрибута с помощью phpQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, phpquery

Добрый день. Например, есть следующий код на HTML:

```html
<ul id="place" class="svc">
  <li class="1">Header
    <li class="curved">text1</li>
  </li>
  <li class="2">Header
    <li class="curved">text2</li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Мне нужно с помощью библиотеки phpQuery получить значения всех классов дочернего к ul тега li (т.е. li с классом"curved" мне не нужен), так как в коде сайта, для которого пишу парсер, слишком много классов для того, чтобы вытаскивать их по одному. Написал такой код:

```
$content = '<ul id="place" class="svc">
<li class="1">Header            
<li class="curved">text1</li></li>
<li class="2">Header            
<li class="curved">text2</li></li>';
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($content); //передаем код phpQuery
$head_elements = $document->find('ul.svc');
foreach($head_elements as $place){
    $pq = pq($place);
    $places = $pq->find('li')->attr('class');
    echo $places;
}
```

В результате я получаю лишь значение самого первого класса. Т.е. echo выводит:

```
1
```

А мне нужно получить 1, 2 и т.д.
Подскажите, каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: вы в цикле же списки перебираете а не элементы. цикла по элементам то нет нигде. Вам нужно ведь что-то вроде `ul.svc > li` ?

Comment: @teran спасибо, вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил. Костыли, конечно, и еще те... Если у кого-то есть предложения, буду рад послушать.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url); //загрузка страницы
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($content); //передаем код phpQuery
$head_elements = $document->find('ul.svc > li');
echo $head_elements;
foreach($head_elements as $place){
    $pq = pq($place);
    $places = $pq->attr('class');
    if ($places != 'curved')
            echo '<br>'.$places.'</br>';
}
```

Comment: если у вас `.curved` может быть у прямого потомка то сделайте `ul.svc > li:not(.curved)`

Comment: и разве вы не можете вызвать `$place->attr('class')` сразу, без `pq()` ?